# How to remove 0 after the price type changed

Tags: php

I have a code that change price type get from database . But it not run as i want. See example

1 200 000 000  -> 1 bil 200 mil (ok)

25 500 000     -> 25 mil 500 thousand (ok)

25 000 000     -> 25 mil 0 thousand (not ok , i want to remove 0 thousand)

25 000         -> 0 mil 25 thousand ( not ok too , i want to remove 0 mil)

I try to fix but it not work . Here's my code ($number is price i get from database)

```
            $billions = $number % 1000000000;
            $billion = ($number - $billions) / 1000000000; 

            $millions = $billions % 1000000;
            $million = ($billions - $millions) / 1000000; 

            $thousands = $millions % 1000;                
            $thousand = ($millions - $thousands) / 1000;
            if($billion == 0)
            {
                $number=  $million . ' mil ' . $thousand .' thous ' ;
            }
            elseif($million == 0)
            {
                $number=  $thousand .' thous ' ;
            }
            elseif($thousand == 0)
            {
                $number= $billion . ' bil '. $million . ' mil '  ;
            }
            elseif($billion == 0 && $thousand == 0)
            {
                $number=  $million . ' mil ' ;
            }
            else
            {
                $number= $billion . ' bil '. $million . ' mil ' . $thousand .' thous ' ;
            }
```

Comment: Don't put all your possible combinations in the if/elseif/else statements. Instead, write your if statement such that you print the billion/million/thousand part only if the amount is not zero. Doing so will help you skip the case where the number is printed even if it's zero.

Comment: or you can treat the number as a string and count the zeros in it, and decide by number of zeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function here might help:

```
<?php

    if (!function_exists('nice_number')) {

    function nice_number($n) {
        // first strip any formatting;
        $n = (0 + str_replace(",", "", $n));
        // is this a number?
        if (!is_numeric($n))
            return false;
        // now filter it;
        $str = '';
        if ($n > 1000000000000) {
            $str = round(($n / 1000000000000), 0) . ' tn ';
            $str .= $n % 1000000000000 > 0 ? nice_number($n % 1000000000000) : '';
            return $str;
        }
        else if ($n > 1000000000) {
            $str = round(($n / 1000000000), 0) . ' bn ';
            $str .= $n % 1000000000 > 0 ? nice_number($n % 1000000000) : '';
            return $str;
        }
        else if ($n > 1000000) {
            $str = round(($n / 1000000), 0) . ' mn ';
            $str .= $n % 1000000 > 0 ? nice_number($n % 1000000) : '';
            return $str;
        }
        else if ($n > 1000)
            return round(($n / 1000), 0) . ' K ';

        return number_format($n);
    }

}

echo nice_number(300200000);
```

and the result:

```
echo nice_number(300200000); //  outputs 300 mn 200 K
```

and

```
echo nice_number(3000000000); // outputs 300 bn
```

[Here](http://3v4l.org/0FCrb) is a fiddle showing the answer

Comment: sorry , but i test 300200000 it return 300,2mil . But i want it 300mil 200 thousand

Comment: I try to test 300000000 it return 300mil 0 or 3000000000 it return 3 bil 0. Do you know to remove that 0 ?

Comment: @user3577430, modified the answer, Please check

Comment: i'm very appreciate for your help . Thanks You very much . It work perfectly :)

Comment: Just a note, using `round()` will round your decimal number to the nearest integer. So in case of something like 25500000, your function will output "26 mn 500 K". Use `floor()` to round down instead.

Answer (score 0):

instead of having all these elseifs, just do this

```
$number="";

if($billion!=0)
$number=$number .  $billion ' bil ';
if($million!=0)
$number=$number . $million . ' mil ';
if($thousand!=0)
$number=$number . $thousand . 'thousands';
```

Comment: it still have bug , when i test 200000 , it return 200,000,200 thousand ... 320200000 it return 320,200,000,320 mil 200thousand ... Now I want to remove number before 320 mil . DO you know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to post an answer to complement my comment above:

```
// Sample data
$numbers = array (1200000000,
                  200000,
                  25000,
                  25000000,
                  25500000,
                  320200000,
                 );

foreach ($numbers as $num)
{
    print "{$num} -> " . formatter ($num) . "\n";
}


// Here's the function
function formatter ($number)
{
    $bil = floor ($number / 1000000000);
    $millions = $number % 1000000000;

    $mil = floor ($millions / 1000000);
    $thousands = $millions % 1000000;

    $thou = floor ($thousands / 1000);

    $str = '';

    if ($bil != 0)
    {
        $str .= "{$bil} billions ";
    }
    if ($mil != 0)
    {
        $str .= "{$mil} millions ";
    }
    if ($thou != 0)
    {
        $str .= "{$thou} thousands ";
    }

    return $str;
}
```

Sample output:

```
    1200000000 -> 1 billions 200 millions 
    200000 -> 200 thousands 
    25000 -> 25 thousands 
    25000000 -> 25 millions 
    25500000 -> 25 millions 500 thousands 
    320200000 -> 320 millions 200 thousands
```

Comment: Thanks you , but my problem sloved